# In Android----Days widget not update when System date change by user

Tags: android, android-widget, datepicker

Android Days Widget since days not change when User change date Manually.
But Days left is automatically called when user change Date Manually.

I used Date Picker in code.

Thanks.

Comment: i thing you had make mistak to calculate days diffrence.

Answer (score 0):

use this...

```
    <receiver
        android:name=".WidgetProvider1_1"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
         >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.TIME_SET"/>
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
            android:resource="@xml/widget_info1_1" />
    </receiver>
```